# How to get value from radio button and input box using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have made form which has 1 question. There are 4 radio button options and 1 input box for `other` radio button. How can I get value from the input box if the other radio button is checked.

```
class ContactForm extends Component {

  setGender(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

render(){

<form>
<div id="gender" onChange={this.setGender.bind(this)}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <h4>What is your gender?</h4>  
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender"/> Female</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender"/> Male</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender"/> Prefer not to say</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender"/>Other</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-inline" id="other1"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</form>
}
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: You mean activate the input field only if Other is clicked?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings If I click on other then it should return the value inside input (only if other is clicked).

Comment: kind of https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/115085/  ?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings How can I get value from input box if other is selected  also how to get value from radio buttons too?

Comment: @G_S Looks good can you post the answer

Comment: Happy that it worked for you. Posted as answer. Check it and let me know if  that resolves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make some changes to your component.

Created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/115104/) for it

Added the below methods to make it work.

```
setGender(checkedValue){
    console.log(checkedValue);
    if(checkedValue == '-1'){
     // get data from text box
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check if this suits your answer. we can change it if needed.

Comment: Your answer works like a charm just edit `checkedValue == '-1'` to `checkedValue === '-1'`.

Comment: Yea, missed that. better to add ===

Comment: btw, for 'other' input text, we have use className. Its currently class

Comment: I could not understand this `if(checkedValue === '-1'){` ?

Comment: to identify the last radio button, I am passing -1 as my identifier. for other radio buttons I am passing someother value. Upon selecting a radio button, the checkedValue is -1, then I am treating 'other' is selected and then I will get data from textbox

Comment: Your answer is perfect but when I click on other it logs -1 in console but when I type text in input. How can I console log it ?

Comment: Ok. let me check if I can make some changes to it

Comment: I want to put the text entered inside input box (if and only if other is checked) inside database that's why I want to store the latest value entered inside the input box.

Comment: Ok till then do you that text box to be disabled then?

Comment: No not disable. I just want to get the input from the input box and store it in variable so that I can push it into my data base when form is submitted.

Comment: check the updated fiddle. However when getting data to be submitted to database, you can read textbox value from state (if using state) when clicking other radio button and then use it. Or use other radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ContactForm extends Component {
  state = {
    gender: "",
    otherValue: ""
  };

  onChanged = event => {
    this.setState({ otherValue: event.target.value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.otherValue);
    });
  };

  setGender = event => {
    this.setState({ gender: event.target.value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.gender);
    });
  };

  onSubmit = () => {
    if (this.state.gender == "other") {
      let other = this.state.otherValue;
        /// do something
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div id="gender" onChange={this.setGender}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <h4>What is your gender?</h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div className="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" /> Female
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div className="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" /> Male
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div className="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="NoSay" /> Prefer not
                  to say
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div className="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" />Other
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-inline"
                  id="other1"
                  onChange={this.onChanged}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

you can use the **onSubmit** method to take the value of the Other input